# Greek-Letters-Different in AdobeReader and TexStudio, who's right?

Tags: pdf, texstudio, greek, matlab

I want to use greek letters in my Matlab Figures and then use the figures in Latex. I'm using TexStudio, and the preview inside of TexStudio shows me, for example if I entered a `\mu` in Matlab something similiar to an alpha. If I take a look at the created pdf with AdobeReader, I see the correct mu.
I'm afraid now, that if I want to print the Document later on from a professional printshop they print the wrong Letters.

Is there a way to determine which version is the "normal" and which program is showing me the wrong letter?

Comment: PDF files are less likely than plaintext files to suffer from encoding problems, but they’re more likely to have font problems. If the PDF is looking correct, though, it should do so everywhere, hence “portable document format”.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: If the version of Adobe Reader is up-to-date: Adobe Reader.

Comment: TeXstudio uses poppler for rendering. So other viewers based on poppler will have the same issue. In terms of 'normal' I'd probably trust Adobe Reader more.